# React state (hook) resets on re-render while using switch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

See codebox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/component-issue-snj24?file=/src/App.js:0-1254

Whenever Main re-renders, the current component rendered conditionally though the switch will have its state reset `const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0)`.

If I took any of the components (comp1, comp2, comp3) and inserted it into the main return (replacing ) this does not occur.

-- Update
As noticed by Dennis, its due to function being nested. Alternative
https://codesandbox.io/s/component-issue-forked-uejy1

Comment: Please show full example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), what does "resets whenever the parent re-renders", resets to what? Maybe its a bug in the component itself.

Comment: Updated description.

Comment: Can you show the whole `RenderActivePage` component?

Comment: That is the whole `RenderActivePage `. A switch which return a component based on "activePage".

Comment: Updated again. Don't know how I can make the question more concise, its very straight forward.

Comment: Created codebox stating the exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component does not "re-render" **it unmounts**, because you declared `RenderActivePage` in function's body, on every render it re-assigned, meaning it re-mounts on every render.

```
export default function App() {
  // remounts on every render
  const RenderActivePage = () => {
    switch (activePage) {
      case 0:
        return <Comp1 />;
      case 1:
        return <Comp2 />;
      default:
        return <div></div>;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RenderActivePage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But its the change of an unused variable in main `value` which triggers the unmount, `activePage` on which the switching occur remains unchanged.

Comment: I changed the answer didn't notice, you are right, check it now

Comment: Ah I see. Didn't think about the function being nested, thanks for clearing it up. Posted alternative in original post.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was already answered a while ago but the answer helped me solve my problem and so just wanted to add my 2 cents.  It seems like when a child component is inside any condition in a parent, for example :

```
{ isTrue && <ChildComponent/> } 
// or  
{ isTrue ? <ChildComponent1/>  : <ChildComponent2/> }
```

or a switch like above then the child component is unmounted and re-mounted on every re-render of the parent. This ends up resetting the local state in the child component on every re-render of the parent.
To solve this problem, I ended up passing the condition to the child as a prop i.e  `<ChildComponent isTrue={isTrue} />`  and then conditionally rendering inside the child.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently.
As Dennis said, it is due to function redefinition.
Eventually I figured out that this problem could be solved by a very minor change.

Just change the JSX instantiation to a JSX expression (General function call):

from

```
<RenderActivePage />
```

to

```
{ RenderActivePage() }
```

Because it's not instantiated using JSX, React will not manage the lifecycle of the `RenderActivePage` element itself.
That is, it won't treat `RenderActivePage` as an element, but will simply output the result of this function.

This approach actually has the same effect as inlining an expression in return:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Pressing "update main component" resets child state</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)}>update main component</button>
      {(() => {
        switch (activePage) {
          case 0:
            return <Comp1 />;
          case 1:
            return <Comp2 />;
          default:
            return <div></div>;
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  );
```